# Toggle cookies & classes when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to figure out a way in order to toggle cookies + classes when a button is pressed.

If: button with a class name of `btn_fixed` is pressed it:
- sets cookie "fixed" to "true",
- adds class to the "`<header>`" called "fixed", **also when the page is loaded any other time the class "fixed" is applied, as the cookie is set to true**.
Else:
- sets cookie "fixed" to "false" (default value, when entering the site for the first time),
- removes class "fixed" from the "`<header>`"

This is what I got so far, which I can now see is very far from what I want it to do:

```
if (jQuery.cookie("fixed") != "true") {  
        jQuery('a.fixed_btn').click(function () {  
            jQuery('header').addClass('fixed');  
            jQuery.cookie("fixed", "true");  
        });  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        jQuery('a.fixed_btn').click(function () {  
            jQuery('header').removeClass('fixed');  
    jQuery.cookie("fixed", "false");
    }  



<a href="#" class="fixed_btn">Fixed/Fluid</a>  
<header>aaa</header>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UWLdq/7/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add the relevant html/css/javascript to your question. Your question should be able to stand up on it's own without external resources so that in the event jsfiddle is down (or unavailable in x network), your question is still valid and answerable.

Comment: add the jquery cookie plugin link to the jsfiddle as as resource, this will help solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just toggle the class initially, then bind a click event that does it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // set class initially based on current cookie value
    $('.cookiefixed').toggleClass('fixed', $.cookie("fixed") == "true");
    // on click, toggle both class and cookie value
    $('a.fixed_btn').click(function() {
        $('.cookiefixed').toggleClass('fixed');
        $.cookie("fixed", $('.cookiefixed').hasClass('fixed'));
    });
});​
```

<strike>I suggest not using `'header'` as a selector though due to the fact that there can be more than one header on a page, and i doubt you'd want them all to get this class.</strike>

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UWLdq/6/

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is happening here... `!!$.cookie("fixed")`

Comment: basically, `$.cookie("fixed")` can return `"true"`, `"false"`, or `undefined`. `!!` converts that value to `true`, `false`, or `undefined`. `!!` is just a double `!`. `!true === false`, and `!!true === true`. Since the toggleClass is expecting a boolean value, I made sure to give it one to avoid bugs.

Comment: So its basically toggling the class only if `$.cookie("fixed") === true` ??

Comment: Right. toggleClass has a second parameter that if true, will always add the class, and if false, will always remove it. That second parameter must be a boolean value, it can't be truethy/falsey according to the api.

Comment: I take it this wouldn't work if the actual value for $.cookie("fixed") was something other than true/false...

Comment: My previous previous comment has a typo. It should be: *`!!` converts that value to `true` or `false`.*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20410/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-videsignz)

Comment: I didn't mean to click chat. Yes, it will work regardless of the cookie value.

Comment: Anything that isn't undefined, 0, false, null, or "false" will equate to true, the rest will be false.

Comment: Thank you, this should do the work, although do you know what is the best way to change this to do the same things for: `<header>`, `.content`, and `<footer>`?

Comment: Give them all a common class, such as .cookiefixed and use that in place of `header`

Comment: Oh man, I was following you, but now I'm lost... 'Anything that isn't undefined, 0, false, null, or "false" will equate to true, the rest will be false'

Comment: @VIDesignz note the **isn't**, i probably could have worded that better. *Anything that is `0` `false` `undefined` or `"false"` will equate to `false`(boolean), anything else will be `true`(boolean).*

Comment: @VIDesignz actually... i'm wrong... !!"false" is true because it's a string. :)

Comment: oh ok...that makes more sense x)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$(document).on('click','a.fixed_btn',function(){   
    var fixed = jQuery.cookie("fixed");              
    jQuery('header').toggleClass('fixed');
    jQuery.cookie("fixed", fixed === "true" ? "false" : "true");

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UWLdq/5/

Comment: This works well, but the OP also needs to check the cookie on page load. Nice work though!

Answer (score 0):

Working off of Bluetoft's answer, you'll need to check the cookie on page load as well.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/UWLdq/8/)

```
$(document).on('click','a.fixed_btn',function(){   
    var fixed = jQuery.cookie("fixed");              
    jQuery('header').toggleClass('fixed');
    jQuery.cookie("fixed", fixed === "true" ? "false" : "true");

});

if ($.cookie("fixed") != "true") {
    $('header').addClass('fixed');
}else{
    $('header').removeClass('fixed');
}
```